# Unable to create Files on enforced device

Tags: android, android-permissions, selinux, android-9.0-pie, capability

I have a system service that is creating a folder and some files under /data/vendor/

Since I have a rooted Android device in Enforcing state, the sepolicy is not permitting me to do this so I am using the dac_override capability in an allow rule - which works.

Now, I am trying to import the code to the Beta version of Android P / 9.0, but in domain.te file they added this capability to the neverallow list :(

When I am not using this capability and trying to use

```
File _file = new File(PATH);
```

The result is that _file is always null!

Can anyone suggest a way to create my files??

Comment: Resort to `shell` commands, with `su`. It's the most foolproof method I know. Example: `su -c touch filename.ext`

Comment: I need the solution programmatically...

Comment: This can be done in Java. Take a look here: https://www.linglom.com/programming/java/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

Comment: Try this: `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c touch filename.ext");`

Comment: It doesn't compile....

Is there other option? using SELinux rules maybe??

Comment: I haven't used SELinux rules before... What is the error you get while compiling?

Comment: error: <identifier> expected
                Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c touch /data/vendor/misc/");
                                       ^
error: illegal start of type
                Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c touch /data/vendor/misc/");
                                        ^



Can I run this command from cmd just to make sure it will solve my original problem of not being able to create files?

Comment: So it didnt help anyways.... I am still getting null when creating new File object